# Swift: set variable before performing segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, cell

I've a tableView with a cell for each pokemon in the "pokedex". When I press a button in the Cell, I want to show a view with details about this creature.

What I do is that I have a global variable "currentPokemon", that I set to the requested pokemon when the button is pressed. Here's my code for the Cell :

```
class PokemonTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var pokemon: Pokemon!
    @IBOutlet weak var pokemonImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var releaseDateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func setPokemon(sender: UIButton) {
        currentPokemon = self.pokemon

    }
}
```

When I try to access the currentPokemon var in the details view, I get a fatal error because currentPokemon is nil. How could I get this code to be executed before the segue ?

Comment: Use can send your `pokemon` to next controller via `prepareForSegue` method. But for your case - where do you store `currentPokemon`?

Comment: You're not setting `pokemon` to anything.  You're just creating the variable but never initializing it.

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov it is stored in a .swift file, outside the Pokemon class definition, it is accessible from the other views, it works if I set a "default" pokemon.

Comment: Which object store it? Is it a singleton?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup it is initialized when the cell is created in the TableViewController, I can access its name and other values.

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov it is simply declared as `var currentPokemon: Pokemon!`outside of any class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add store for selected Pokemon with singleton instance like:

```
struct Pokemon {
    let name: String
}

class PokemonStore {

    static let instance = PokemonStore()
    var currectPokemon: Pokemon?
}
```

Later you can get saved pokemon in any place of your code with `PokemonStore.instance.currectPokemon`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using segue, you should pass data to detail controller in this `UIViewController` method:

`func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?)`

Comment: That's an overrride function and you need to format your post as code.